# HTML navigation menus linked to separate html files, when each menu is clicked to show the content of the html file linked to each menu

Tags: html

I started learning Html and CSS two weeks ago, and am trying to build my first website. As you can see from the attached image, I want to link each menu (Home, About Us, Our Product, Contact Us) to a separate html file so that when each menu is clicked I want to show the content of each html file in the Orange colored area below. I tried Target=_blank, _self, _parent, _top) but they all opened the html files in a separate page. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi Solomon, I can't see any attached image...

Comment: Thanks gbellmann, I tried to attach an image of the website but I couldn't.

Comment: Attach image and code you are using please so we can see it and suggest what to with your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the target attribute all together and simply use href to point to your desired file. It will open in the same tab by default.

Comment: Thanks Mimo, as advised I removed the targets but when I clicked the menus they still open up the linked html files on separate page rather than the parent page

Comment: @Solomon could you please submit a snippet of your code to take a closer look at?